# Rails - need universal back link for each page in application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Probably more than anything else I'm looking for a sanity check here.

So I have an application with a lot of different models and many of the models have nested models down to n-level.  I've been trying to build a back link helper which will provide a link which steps the user back up the path they took to get to this page.  Since there are multiple ways a user could arrive at a page, I'm not able to hard code the back link in every scenario.

Here is what I have now, which is not working too well.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :store_url, if: :current_user

  def skipped_routes
    ["edit", "new", "submit", "aprove", "revert", "add", "add_options", "unschedule", "complete", "assign", "unasign", "select", "resend", "disable", "activate"]
  end

  def store_url
    tree = session[:my_previous_url].split(",")
    if tree.last == request.original_url
       session[:my_previous_url] = tree.pop
    elsif request.referer != tree.last and skipped_routes.exclude? request.referer.split("/").last
      session[:my_previous_url] << ",#{request.referer}"
    end
  end
end
```

Then in the helper file

```
    module ApplicationHelper
      def back_link(path= nil)
        unless path.blank?
          link_to path, class: "back_link" do
            concat content_tag :i, "", class: "fas fa-chevron-left"
            concat "Back"
          end

        else
          last = session[:my_previous_url].split(",").last
          link_to last, class: "back_link" do
            concat content_tag :i, "", class: "fas fa-chevron-left"
            concat "Back"
          end
        end
      end
```

The trouble I'm having is the logic in the store_url method of the application controller.  I'd like it to simply evaluate, between the two scenarios.

The first scenario being where the current page is the same url as the most recently stored path.  In this case the user would have clicked the back link, and is now looking at the page that is before the last page the visited.

In the event that the user wasnt just on this page, then I would like the method to append the previous page the array of visited pages.

has anyone encountered this kind of issue before? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Read it now couple of times, what exactly doesn't work? And minor edit use `array << "my string"` . Your code leads to `["foo.bar", ", some.other.foobar"]`. See the coma in the string of array[1] itself?

Comment: `link_to :back` ?